# CORS : Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors, openshift, same-origin-policy

I am trying to integrate the angualar js app with the backend spring boot , in which i am facing the redirection is not allowed for a preflight request

This is deployed on openshift , i have configured to enabled cors by adding few annotation in the controller method , which helped me to solve the : 
 Request doesnot have "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in the incoming request : CORS policy issue.

```
    @CrossOrigin(allowedHeaders = "*", origins = "*", exposedHeaders = 
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", methods = {
          RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.PUT, 
    RequestMethod.DELETE, RequestMethod.HEAD,
          RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.PATCH, RequestMethod.TRACE })
    @RestController
    public class Controller {

   @Autowired
   Service botService;

   @Autowired
   Environment env;

   @CrossOrigin()
   @RequestMapping(value = "/jwtToken", method = {
                 RequestMethod.POST }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
   public ResponseEntity<UnifiedService> botConntor(                     
                 @RequestBody UnifiedInput input, HttpServletRequest request) {
          UnifiedBPMService output = botService.processBotRequest(input, request);
          return new ResponseEntity<UnifiedService>(output, HttpStatus.OK);
   }
```

The error which i get in the actual angular app is:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http:///chatbot/api/jwtToken' from 
>           origin 'http://' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response 
>           to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not 
>           allowed for a preflight request.

The options call has returned the below respose :

```
    Request URL: http://<domain>/chatbot/api/jwtToken
    Request Method: OPTIONS
    Status Code: 302 Found
    Remote Address: 10.235.222.220:80
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Comment: You can try adding @CrossOrigin(origins = { "*" }, maxAge = 4800, allowCredentials = "false") but origins should be * and remove exposed headers

Comment: @AhmadQureshi :  the suggested changes did not help to solve the problem. still i get the same error

Comment: can you try removing @CorsOrigin from the method level

Comment: @AhmadQureshi : removed, but still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Your backend is redirecting (302) instead of sending a proper response (200) to the OPTIONS/preflight request. Check your backend logs to see why it is redirecting. It may be something like Spring security denying the OPTIONS request and redirecting to your login page.

Comment: I am facing the same issue but the backend log does not have any data at all.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. When you are using an SSO server, you need to do a redirection on the server side instead of sending `403`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help at all, but Spring security logging is generally very minimal in situations like this. The first step I always go to is enabling debug logging. Try `-Dlogging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG`

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue. My problem is it redirects to login page because i used Spring Security. To see if it is the same with you, you can see server logs. But you need to enable logging for Spring Security.
For spring boot projects, in application.yml file:

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        security: DEBUG
```